# Remove environment message in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

In my r markdown file, I am outputting to html.  In the code, I include"

`{r,  fig.align= "center", message= FALSE, warning= FALSE}`

This removes all warnings and messages except this one:

```
   ## <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Somewhere in the code I convert a list to objects in the environment with:

```
list2env(a1, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

So I understand where the message is coming from but do not understand why it is not being removed by `message = FALSE, warning = FALSE`

Any suggetions?

Comment: Reproducible example, or the question doesn't exist. I have written many Rmd documents and have never seen that message. So ...

Comment: Sure, I will prepare a reproducible example just a moment

Comment: thanks, how would one do that - I mean - wrap with invisible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not a message, it's the output of `list2env()`.

Note: Don't run the following line if you don't want new objects in your global environment.

```
list2env(mtcars, .GlobalEnv)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

You can suppress the output of a function by wrapping it with `invisible()`.

```
invisible(list2env(a1, envir = .GlobalEnv))
```